remove default backbutton background color
I would like to remove the background color of the default backbutton. I have below configurations but it still appears like in the photo. TIA for all inputs.

hightlightColor: Colors.transparent,
splashColor: Colors.transparent,
splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,

Thanks in advance.

Have you used Icon Button?

i did not want to use any widgets as i would want to override the theming in the whole app. wondering if there's any solutions for that

I found a way to override the theming in the whole app. Set the following in ThemeData and provide it to theme in MaterialApp.
iconButtonTheme: IconButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
          splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
        ),
      ),

Additionally, to remove all tooltip in the automaticallyImplyLeading button, I came across the following:
class BackButtonOverride extends DefaultMaterialLocalizations {
  BackButtonOverride(Locale locale) : super();

  @override
  String get backButtonTooltip => '';
}

class BackButtonDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  const BackButtonDelegate();
  @override
  Future<BackButtonOverride> load(Locale locale) {
    return SynchronousFuture(BackButtonOverride(locale));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(BackButtonDelegate old) => false;
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => true;
}

and applied to MaterialApp as follows:
localizationsDelegates: const [
              BackButtonDelegate(),
            ],


Here's a BackButton with transparent background:
BackButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
                surfaceTintColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
              )
          ),

Use it as a reusable widget, because if you are trying to deal with the Theme, to change that back button you will be forced to change all of the IconButtons Theme. because back button is considered as an IconButton.
    ThemeData(
      iconButtonTheme: IconButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent,)
 // will be applied to all of the IconButtons
        )
      ),

That's because the leading widget is not made only for the back button, it accepts any widget.
So, it's recommended to be used as a reusable widget.
Hope it helps you.
